# A função substring() do Javascript não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, substring

A função que eu estava usando estava retornando um erro de tipo. Estava tentando converter uma função PHP em JS e me perdi nesse erro mesmo após várias pesquisas. Tentei utilizar várias funções para corrigir o erro, mas não sabia exatamente em quais pontos deveria colocar a função resolutiva.

Uma das respostas abaixo me ajudou na compreensão.

No final, a função `substr()` foi a solução.

A função retorna no console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: string.substring is not a function.
```

```
let string = gerarNumRand();
for (let cont = 0; cont < 5; cont++) {
    let aux = string.substring(cont, 1);
    for (let cont1 = 0; cont1 <= 9; cont1++) {
        if (aux === cont1) {
            idDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='img/nrosrandomicos/"+cont1+".jpg'>";
        }
    }
}
```

Não sei qual o erro, já tentei "substr" também, como no PHP e nada.

Comment: A função `gerarNumRand` retorna o que? Provavelmente não é uma string, daí o erro...

Comment: retorna 5 números aleatórios

Comment: function gerarNumRand() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) + 11111;
}

Comment: O erro provavelmente é pq está retornando um numero e usando uma função de string. tenta coloca 'toString()' para forçar virar uma string, tanto no 'string.substring' quanto no 'aux === cont1' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que está mostrando no console é por estar utilizando uma função de strng em um valor numérico. Para resolver o problema uma opção seria utilizar a função 'toString()' para forçar a conversão dos valores para uma string.

Modificando o seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
let string = gerarNumRand();
for (let cont = 0; cont < 5; cont++) {
    let aux = string.toString().substring(cont, 1);
    for (let cont1 = 0; cont1 <= 9; cont1++) {
        if (aux === cont1.toString()) {
            idDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='img/nrosrandomicos/"+cont1+".jpg'>";
        }
    }
}
```

Creio que ao fazer essas alterações o problema deve ser resolvido.

Comment: Funcionou! Da sua resposta eu só alterei a função de: substring(cont, 1); para: substr(cont, 1); E deu certo. Obrigada!

Comment: Na verdade o toString deveria ser chamado antes, fica meio redundante chamar .toString em uma variavel que se chama string, no caso o parse deveria ser chamado na hora de atribuir o valor para a variável de nome string, e alias, o nome string não é bom, pq é um tipo, provavelmente alguma ferramenta de lint já reclamaria disso.